# Passing data from HTML to update a Google Sheet row

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I get some data values from a form in HTML and need to update them in a specific row of a Google SpreadSheet.
If the user select the first element in the list, then I have to update the first row in the Sheet.

I already have the data that needs to be updated and the index value of the row , but dont know what method, function or API to use in order that I can do something like this:

```
function update () {
    updateRow("SpreadSheet_URL", index, dataToUpdate)
}
```

I use this method to fetch the data from the google spreadsheet

```
function openload() {
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/KEY/edit#gid=0';

    Tabletop.init({
        key: public_spreadsheet_url,
        callback: loadInfo,
        parseNumbers: true
    });

};
```

And this other code to save it, but it saves in a new row, dont update a existing one.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/KEY/formResponse?',
        data: {
            "entry.2085722051": name
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (d) {
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {

            $('#success-msg').show();
            $('#form').hide();
        }
    });
```

As I say before, what I needs is to update a row, but what is happening is that the method that i use, is saving the data in a new row in the spreadsheet

If anyone knows what can I use to specify the row number in Ajax, Jquery or JavaScript or how to pass the data and row number to Google Apps Script in order to do the update function there.

Comment: Hi! I did a integration using Google API / PHP to this.

Comment: Why not just use [tag:google-sheets-api]?

Comment: @TheMaster Can I use the google-sheets-api with pure JavaScript? Everything I have found is in Node.js

Comment: @pls See bottom of the [page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get). The first one is sample browser code.

Comment: In here there's a complete example to update a Sheet using JS: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update